# update stuck on windows 8.1 update 2

Tags: update, insider-preview, windows-10-mobile

I have been using windows phone 8.1 update 2 being installed through windows insider app as i am upgrading to windows 10 second time. But after upgrading to windows 8.1 upgrade 2 phone update downloading has been stuck to 6%. My wifi data connection shows downloading but there is no progress in terms of percentage.

Any solution to the same?

Comment: Resetting the phone might work
Then you have to start afresh

Answer (score 1):

That's a bug with Windows Phones. Actually the download is done in the background, but is not displayed correctly. Give time and the download percentage will jump to a later stage. Do not reset the device for this issue.